# How to draw a frame around a subreport which extends beyond its parent band?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I have a report in which a multi-column subreport is placed on my `TfrxMasterData` band. At design time, the report looks like this:
[image: Master Data]
And the subreport looks like this:
[image: Subreport]

I want to draw a frame around my data band, so I placed a `TfrxShapeView` on `MasterData1` with `Align = baClient` and `Shape = skRectangle`. As long as the subreport does not exceed the design-time height of `MasterData1`, everything looks fine. But when there is more than four lines of data, my shape does not extend and the result looks like this:
[image: Generated report]

Notice the gap between data bands? It seems that while my subreport correctly stretches to display additional lines, the shape on my master data band is not notified of this despite being aligned to `baClient`. Any thoughts?

I'm using FastReport 4.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to FastReport manual, you have to set `SubReport.PrintOnParent` and `MasterData.Stretched` to `True` in order for the *parent* band to be stretched to match subreport's height.

Comment: iMan Biglari do you have any solution to this one Fast Report grid layout related problem at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635509/how-to-show-data-at-fast-report-in-33-grid-format)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on one of my reports and I think it is doing what you want.  I put the TfrxShapeView onto a TfrxSubdetailData (which is the data band that stretches in my report).  On the TfrxSubdetailData, I checked the Stretched option to make it true.  I aligned the TfrxShapeView to alClient and it worked.  Maybe you are just missing checking the box to have the data band stretch.

Comment: My subreport is multi column. Thus, the box is drawn around every column instead of the whole subreport.

Comment: I remember that multi-column reports had some limitations.  I assume you tried this with your report and it did not work.  I don't have any multi-column reports to test so I won't be any help right now.  Good luck.